# update database record with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Having an issue with updating the user's firstname and lastname database record from the search results.The query runs fine and updates the database record but it does this for the wrong selected user.

search_user.php

```
        <?php require_once("includes/db.php"); ?>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function(){
$('.edit').on('click', function (e) {

    var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
    var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
   var user_id = $('#user_id').val();

    var dataString = 'firstname='+firstname + '&lastname='+lastname+ '&user_id='+user_id ;



                  if(firstname=='' || lastname=='')
                    {
                    alert("Please fill all fields");
                    }

                      else
                    {
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "update_users.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(){

                        alert("User details have been updated.")
                    }
                    });
                    }
     return false;
});

               });
  </script>

         <?php

            $output = "";


            $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0){

                     $output .= '<h4 align="center"> Search Result </h4>';

                 $output .= '


                    <table class="table table-bordered">

                    <thead>

                    <th>First Name </th>
                    <th>Last Name </th>
                    <th colspan="2">Options </th>

                    </thead>

            ';

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];

                    $output .= '

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>

                        <td><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="'.$row["first_name"].'"></td>
                        <td> <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="'.$row["last_name"].'"></td>
                        <td> <a href="search_user.php?edit='.$row["user_id"].'" class="edit">Edit </a> </td>
                         <td> <a href="search_user.php?delete='.$row["user_id"].'" class="delete_confirmation">Delete </a> </td>
                        </tr>

<input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="'.$row["user_id"].'">

                        </tbody>

                    ';

                }

            echo $output;

            } else {

                echo "User not found!";
            }



            ?>
```

update_user.php

```
 <?php require_once("includes/db.php"); ?>


     <?php

     if (isset($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'], $_POST['user_id'])) {


     $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
     $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);


     $query = "UPDATE users
        SET first_name  ='" . $_POST['firstname'] . "',
         last_name ='" . $_POST['lastname'] . "'

                  WHERE
        user_id = '" .  $_POST['user_id']  . "'";


                  $edit_user_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                    } 
                else {
            echo "invalid response";
                }

              ?>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing `session_start()` anywhere. You're also escaping your data and then ignoring that and using the raw data in the query (so it's not any more secure against SQL injection). Finally, you're storing passwords in plain text, which is a bad idea. Use [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to secure those

Comment: Machavity - session start is stored in the db file which i have included. Passwords?? lol not related this query.

Comment: that ^ isn't the only thing failing here. Don't people read manuals to a T?

Comment: Fred - if you don't want to help. Then please don't comment.

Comment: again. RTM man. so instead of asking what you did wrong, you basically tell me to go to help lol fine.

Comment: Fred, im trying here. Posted code for advice and resolution. Bye Fred.

Comment: @steven what do you mean about wrong selected users?

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi say for example:

Comment: say for example: user id - 1 user id -2. When I edit user id 1 it edits user id 2 instead :?

Comment: So i suspect the  $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id']; line, maybe you manipulate it wrong !

Comment: yes that's correct @FarzadSalimiJazi i don't think i have. whenever i hover over the edit link it shows the id for the different users. I am storing the value of this in session variable.

Comment: @steven having this line in your while mean you have the last row user_id in your $_session_id always and if you update it you will update the last one, is it what you want ?

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi oh really silly me lol so will i remove it then? and put it where? thanks.

Comment: @steven I just got a downvote here :))  but happy to help anyway !

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi i get them every time for trying on this site.

Comment: @FarzadSalimiJazi This is still not resolved lol

Comment: Place the use-id as an attribute, and then add it to your datastring. Access the id from the posted datastring instead of the session. As mentioned the session will always hold the last id in the data set

Comment: @KamuNyambe how? var id = $('# ').val(); ??

Comment: Something like var id = $('#firstname').attr('user-id')

Comment: @KamuNyambe i went away from the while loop as it gets the last row. I did what you said and now its gets the first row everytime lol i want based on the url of the edit hyperlink to update that id. why is this not working. see my modified code.

Comment: @Steven I have posted an answer based on you original code

Answer (score -1):

As i mentioned in the comment, you need to lose the dependency on the session.
Place an id on the actual edit link instead. see modified code below:

```
<?php require_once("includes/db.php"); ?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.edit').on('click', function (e) {

        var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
        var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
        var id=$(this).attr('id');

         var dataString = 'firstname='+firstname + '&lastname='+lastname + '&userid='+id;
          if(firstname=='' || lastname=='')
            {
            alert("Please fill all fields");
            }

              else
            {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_users.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){

                alert("User details have been updated.")
            }
            });
            }
         return false;
    });
});
```

```
     <?php

        $output = "";


        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)> 0){

                 $output .= '<h4 align="center"> Search Result </h4>';

             $output .= '


                <table class="table table-bordered">

                <thead>

                <th>First Name </th>
                <th>Last Name </th>
                <th colspan="2">Options </th>

                </thead>

        ';

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];

                $output .= '

                <tbody>
                    <tr>

                    <td><input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="'.$row["first_name"].'"></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" value="'.$row["last_name"].'"></td>
                    <td> <a href="search_user.php?edit='.$row["user_id"].'" class="edit"  id="'.$row["user_id"].'">Edit </a> </td>
                     <td> <a href="search_user.php?delete='.$row["user_id"].'" class="delete_confirmation">Delete </a> </td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>

                ';

            }

        echo $output;

        } else {

            echo "User not found!";
        }



        ?>
```

You can the access the id via post:

```
$userid = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
```

Comment: Why is these changes still only updating first user_id??

Comment: Brilliant! Please mark this as correct if you're happy with the answer